# how to setup build definition/tfs tasks to handle disconnected build agent properly

Tags: tfs, virtual-machine, restore, agent

our project contains some legacy vb6 components which need to be registered to work properly. we have several branches for different releases and those branches contain different versions of those components.

we setup a tfs2018 for code hosting and automated builds, currently we deal with the situation in following manner:

we got a hyper-v host running multiple vms, each vm has all needed toolchains installed. each vm has its own buildagent registered to tfs agent pool.
when we need a new build the vm gets restored to a previously saved snapshot, pull repository, build and deploy the generated binaries.

problem in this case is we need to restore the vm to a clean state before we start the build. at this point of time a buildagent is already assigned and as soon as we restore the vm the connection from agent to tfs gets closed so the build fails.

what we did in the past to solve above issue was a dirty workaround, we created a second build definition which runs on dummy build agent, restores the target vm and excutes the real build on real build agent as soon as the vm is reset to a clean state.

from what i have read there's the possibility to add agentless tasks/phases to a build definition/pipeline however this doesn't provide needed type of task (we either need to establish a ssh session to the hyper-v host or use a powershell remote script (ssh preferable))

is there any possiblity to solve above issue without using a second dummy agent?

problem itsself isn't that complicated, we just need a fresh environment for every build to avoid problems due version conflicts.

thank you :)

Comment: I don't understand your use case here. Are these build agents, or are they servers that are part of a deployment group?

Comment: they are build agents but they need to run in a clean environment where are no registration issues with those vb6 components, that's why we run each agent in it's own vm which can be restored to a specific state.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional phase to your definition that runs before your deployment group phase. Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#types-of-jobs).

Comment: well that's exactly what i mean but has to be done before the build itsself starts. however i didnt find a suitable task type for this agentless phase. as far as i have seen there's not ssh task right?

Comment: It's not an agentless phase. It's an agent pool phase that runs on a machine that's not in your deployment group.

Comment: so i will need another agentpool (with registered agents) for this?or does it work without registered agent as well?

Comment: You need an agent to run it on that isn't part of the deployment group.

Comment: ok, so i still need an additional agent :/ would be one agent sufficient when i use lets say 5 build agents in my pool? or do i still need one additional agent for each agent i run builds on?

Comment: I think a better understanding of what an agent is and what it's used for would help you answer your own question: An agent is just a task runner. You install an agent on the machines in the deployment group so that each of those machines can have tasks run on it. You need a separate agent that's not in that deployment group to run a series of activities that impact the machines *in* the deployment group *before* the deployment group phase. How many agents do you think you need to accomplish that?

Comment: You said *"...we created a second build definition which runs on dummy build agent, restores the target vm and excutes the real build on real build agent..."* This is exactly what you need to still be doing, except you can do it in a single definition by using phases, instead of separate builds.